# Self-sizing cells and NSFetchedResultsController - very slow update

Tags: ios, swift

I have a table view with self sizing cells with NSFetchedResultsController as data source. The problem is if i delete some entry (with swipe to delete) or update it the reloading of the table view is very slow - like 10 sec. I set all delegate methods correctly. What i observed is that if table is set for self sizing cells like:

```
logEntriesTableView.estimatedRowHeight = 80
logEntriesTableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

its very slow. But if its working with fixed sized cells for example:

```
//logEntriesTableView.estimatedRowHeight = 80
logEntriesTableView.rowHeight = 80
```

There is no lag at all. I guess the table view is trying to calculate its content size and that its very slow because the list of entries is arround 15 000. If someone knows how to prevent the lag it will be nice.

Comment: are you sure that you are setting all the needed constraints?

Comment: Alternatively you could overwrite hightForRowAtIndexPath and do the math yourself.

Comment: Yes constraints are correct, i recently changed this VC to use NSFetchedResultsController. Before that i just fetched all entries and populated the table with the same cells and it was working properly.